# Rails: How to retrieve a model's has_many objects as collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Let's say I have something like

```
Country has_many :cities
```

and the model `City` has an attribute `council_id`. Only having an instance of `Country`, what is the best way to retrieve a collection that contains all the relevant `Councils`?

I know this can be easily done passing the `Country` instance to some method and iterating over the `council_ids` but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If city has

```
belongs_to :country
belongs_to :council
```

Then country can have

```
has_many :cities
has_many :councils, :through => :cities
```

And then you can do `some_country.councils`. Behind the scenes this constructs a join query to load the associated councils. This would still work if a city had many councils - `has_many :through` can figure that out

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest way I can think of (assumes you have set the `@country` instance):

```
Council.joins(:city => :countries).where('countries.id = ?', @country.id)
```

You may want to just save the `country_id` for each Council though to make this easier with:

```
@country.councils
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work with Council.joins(:cities => :country).where('countries.id = ?', @country.id)

Answer (score 0):

If Council is model, try following:

```
Council.where(city_id: @country.cities)
```

If council_id is attribute of City model:

```
@country.cities.map {|c| c.council_id}
```